# how to transfer data from one route to another in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm having some trouble transferring info from a form from one route (main) to another route (score)
this is my main route calling the form

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
    form = form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form_data = form.score.data
        return redirect(url_for('main.score', form_data=form_data))
    return render_template('root.html', form=form)
```

and in the score layout i have this

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>{{ form_data.score }}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

i want it to display the score that the user inputs into the form
and i keep getting this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form_data' is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just render the score template instead of trying to redirect to it:

```
return render_template('score.html', form_data=form_data)
```

Comment: so that does seem to work with transferring over the data. however in my score function I'm opening a csv file, and when I render the template within root it doesnt open the file  
```
@main.route('/score')
def score():
 csv_data = []
 with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

  for line in csv_reader:
   csv_data.append(line)

 return render_template('score.html', title='Score', csv_data=csv_data)
```

Comment: So you have to really think how to organize your program/app. You could write a function which returns a list using the csv file, and call that function in your `root` function.